# How do I adjust axes for camera rotated using THREE.DeviceOrientationControls?

Tags: javascript, three.js, device-orientation, perspectivecamera

**The short story**: I am trying to use THREE.TrackballControls to move the camera, but the (upside-down) x-z plane is where the x-y plane should be. Can anyone help?

**The long story**: I've been trying to add device orientation controls to a project. I have already used the THREE.TrackballControls to move the camera when mouse and touch are being used, and the direction the camera points feeds into other functionality. I am using v69 of three.js.

So, I have been looking into using THREE.DeviceOrientationControls to enable device orientation. Specifically, what I'm after is for rotation to be in the x-y plane when the device is upright in front of me and I turn around. Or in other words, when the device is face up on the table it is looking in the -ve z-direction, and when upside down it it looking in the +ve z-direction. Sounds fairly straightforward, right?

There are plenty of examples around to follow, but I seem to be stuck with axes incorrectly orientated, i.e. what should be my x-y plane is coming out as the x-z plane, but upside-down. I created a test page based on an example with a BoxGeometry cube I found, and then added red, yellow and blue spheres to the middle of the faces that corresponded to the +ve x-, y-, and z-directions respectively, and then pale versions of the same coloured spheres for the corresponding -ve directions. Testing this on an iPad confirmed that the scene axes and the real world axes were not lining up.

I have spent a bit of time trying to get to grips with how this Object works, and the main sticking point is in the function returned by setObjectQuaternion() which does the tricky bit:

```
...
return function (quaternion, alpha, beta, gamma, orient) {
    euler.set(beta, alpha, -gamma, 'YXZ'); // 'ZXY' for the device, but 'YXZ' for us
    quaternion.setFromEuler(euler); // orient the device
    quaternion.multiply(q1); // camera looks out the back of the device, not the top
    quaternion.multiply( q0.setFromAxisAngle( zee, - orient ) );    // adjust for screen orientation
}
...
```

where q1 is quaternion for a -pi/2 rotation around the x-axis, and zee is a unit z-axis vector.

I set up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lloydk04/2j1Lqn5f/21/) to help me debug this, but it wasn't rendering correctly on the iPad itself, so I had to add in some faking of orientation events, and plenty of logging, and continue on a normal desktop + console. This jsfiddle goes through each of the 6 basic orientations and sees whether the camera is looking in the direction I expect.

(Initially it would seem that a pi/2 rotation around the x-axis is what is required, but removing the `quaternion.multiply(q1)` doesn't fix it - I haven't even started looking at non-zero screen orientations yet.)

Ultimately, I'd like to make this more like the TrackballControls/OrbitControls with a target point that the camera always looks at (unless panned) and rotates around, once I've figured this "simple" stuff out.

Anybody have any ideas how I can orientate my camera properly?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't help you with an answer, but I might suggest making your post less verbose - that is to say, only mention what is absolutely necessary for users that see this post to come up with an answer for you. The fewer words you can use to get your point across, the better.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a brief version of the problem.